# Attempt to present View Controller which is not in window hierarchy

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My initial view controller is created from Storyboard. It has a button which adds a UINavigation :

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ListViewController)
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion:nil) 
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

ListViewController has a UICollectionView. Tapping on cell (which I subclassed) calls a delegate method back to ListViewController and presents another View with UICollectionView:

```
let detailedListViewController = DetailedCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())  
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailedListViewController, animated: true)
```

Inside this DetailedCollectionView each cell has a button to show a full-screen SFSafariViewController. So as before, using delegate I'm trying to show it like this:

```
SFSafariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: urlToLoad)
SFSafariVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.presentViewController(SFSafariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

By doing so, I can see the SFSafariView working correctly, but I get the message:

> Warning: Attempt to present < UIAlertController: 0x7fcd96353e20 > on
>   < UINavigationController: 0x7fcd948a0600 > whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

I tried changing `self.presentViewController` to `self.navigationController?.presentViewController` but still the same error persists..

Comment: after presenting viewcontroller along with any alert is showing using alertcontroller , it may cause this warning

Comment: I have no alercontroller showing. (If we have in mind the UIAlertViewController)

Comment: when presnting viewcontroller over other presented screen then it shows

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I'm a bit confused. Im trying to show SFSafariViewController from pushedVC (not presented).